# In which container can I collect Strings to show any of them

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have a LinkedHashMap which fills with data from db with loop "for" string by string and when I try to show the first or the last String, the method can show me only the last String in log. But in application listViewContent is filled fully. So I don't understand why I can't see any string that I want. I need to collect all strings I get from db and compare them in future.

How can I collect all strings and what method should I call to show the string I want to see?Unfortunately I can only retrieve one (and the last instead of the first) string.
Here is my example code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FirstMethod();
}

public FirstMethod() {
    SecondMethod newMethod = .. // getting data from the second method
}

public SecondMethod() {
    public void onResponseReceived(String result) {
        try {
            ...
            if (posts != null) {
                for (WallPostItem post : posts) {    // this loop
                    //create new map for a post
                    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
                    map.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, post.text);
                    PictureItem postPicture = new PictureItem();
                    map.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_IMAGE, postPicture);
                    map.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_DATE, post.date);
                    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                };
            };
            ...
            List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Object>>(GlobalMap.entrySet());
            Map.Entry<String, Object> firstInsertedEntry = list.get(0);
            Log.w("FirstEntryOfMap",""+firstInsertedEntry);   // this log shows me the last string instead of the first
        }
        if (isRefresh) {
            isRefresh = false;
            lvSimple.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("exceptions", "problem in get wall post task after post execute: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't putting your values into a `List`, you are putting them into a `Map` (that preserves key order). I would suggest you create a POJO class,

```
class MyAttribute {
  final String postName;
  final PictureItem postPicture;
  final Date postDate;
  public MyAttribute(String postName, PictureItem postPicture, Date postDate) {
    this.postName = postName;
    this.postPicture = postPicture;
    this.postDate = postDate;
  }

  public String getPostName() {
    return postName;
  }
  public Date getPostDate() {
    return postDate;
  }
  public PictureItem getPostPicture() {
    return postPicture;
  }
}
```

Then you could create a

```
List<MyAttribute> myAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: i created but how can I add my db data now? myAttributes.add(post.text) for example doesn't work for me

Comment: Use the constructor `new MyAttribute(post.text, postPicture, post.date)`

Comment: you mean that I must do "new MyAttribute(post.text, post.picture, post.date); List<MyAttribute> myAttributes = new ArrayList<MyAttribute>();" inside "for" loop and then I can for example print in output log my myAttributes data? Is it correct?

Comment: No. Outside the for loop create the List. `List<MyAttribute> myAttributes = new ArrayList<MyAttribute>();` Inside the loop add your attributes to the `List`, with `myAttributes.add(new MyAttribute(post.text, postPicture, post.date));` If you want to log them, you can. You should probably override `toString()` in `MyAttribute` if you want to do that.

Comment: ok, it works great! thank you, but I still have a question. How can I assign myAttributes or how to set parameters (Strings) outside of method which contains loop? I every time get NullPointer or just empty list.I tried to create global variable but I got NullPointer again

Comment: Return the List. Also, this is getting a little ridiculous. Please post a new question when you have one.